# Django unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi I am crating a view for editing a model using model forms.

My forms.py looks like:

```
from user_profile.models import Project
from django.forms import ModelForm


def ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Project
```

And my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from user_profile.models import Project
from user_profile.forms import ProjectForm

def EditProject(request, project_id=None):
    """
    This view allows a user to edit details of a project.
    """
    title = u'Unirac - Edit Project'
    project = Project.objects.get(id=4)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # save form
            form.save()
        else:
            return render_to_response('edit_project.html', {
                'title': title,
                'form': form,
            }, RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = ProjectForm(instance=project)
        return render_to_response('edit_project.html', {
            'title': title,
            'form': form,
        }, RequestContext(request))
```

But I'm getting a `ProjectForm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'` error?

I can't figure out why, as you can pass instance to a model form, can't you?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which version of django or you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def ProjectForm(ModelForm):
```

Unless this is just a typo when posting it here, there's your problem.
You've defined a ProjectForm **function**, not a class.